# How do you modify Ionic colors in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, ionic-framework

I'm using the [official Ionic package](https://atmospherejs.com/driftyco/ionic) for Meteor. Working directly with Ionic, there is a way to [write a SASS](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/working-with-sass/) theme. How would you do this in a Meteor set up?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: No. If I come up with a solution, I'll post it here. Working on other things for now. But I will need to come back to this. So if you learn anything, please post it here. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I found the solution. Check out this repo: https://github.com/nickw/meteor-ionic-scss-import
Just do as it says in the readme and it works out

Comment: Interesting. I'll give it a shot. You should post this as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Yup I just posted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the `fourseven:scss` package
2. Download this repo 
   https://github.com/nickw/meteor-ionic-scss-import and copy all the files to `/client/stylesheets/ionic`
3. In your main scss file, import ionic.import.scss: `@import "./ionic/ionic.import.scss";`
4. Overwrite the colors in `_variables.import.scss`
5. Go have a beer.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at how it was done in [Meteoric](https://github.com/meteoric/meteor-ionic). Although this package is no longer maintained you can reuse the concepts that are used there:

- Use https://atmospherejs.com/meteoric/ionic-sass and https://atmospherejs.com/meteoric/ionicons-sass as prepackaged versions of Ionic SCSS
- Use https://atmospherejs.com/fourseven to make sure Meteor can process SCSS
- To create your custom theme, simply overwrite the variables in _variables.scss in your own stylesheet.

Note that these packages support an older version of Ionic, if you want to use the newest version, you can include it from here in your "style" folder: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/tree/master/scss